# how i can change the flag value

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a flag as a switch "true and false" when the user has clicked the request order button the flag value changing to the "true" and then when the user sent "message" into the chatbot and the flag is true, print work.

```
$flag = false;

if ($text == '/start')
{
  $key = json_encode([ 'inline_keyboard'=> [ [ ['text'=>'view order','callback_data'=>'vOrder'],['text'=>'request order','callback_data'=>'rOrder'] ] ] ]);

bot('sendMessage',['chat_id'=>$chatID,'text'=>'start order','reply_markup'=>$key]);

}

switch ($data) {

  case "rOrder":


  $key = json_encode([ 'inline_keyboard'=> [ [ ['text'=>'cancel the order','callback_data'=>'cnl'] ] ] ]);

     bot('sendMessage',['chat_id'=>$chatID2,'text'=>'1/2

     write describe about your order',

      'reply_markup'=>$key]);
        bot('sendMessage',['chat_id'=>$chatID2,'text'=>$order]);

        $flag = true;

    break;

  case "vOrder":
        bot('sendMessage',['chat_id'=>$chatID2,'text'=>$viewOrder]);
    break;
}

if(!empty($text) and $flag==true){
    bot('sendMessage',['chat_id'=>$chatID,'text'=>'work']);
}
```

Just I want to receive information from the user after has clicked the button other else no

Comment: If you want to know when a user clicks on a button in HTML use Javascript. I am not sure about your questions clarity and context.

Comment: its telegram bot program wrote by PHP

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/api Tried API Docs. I haven't integrated Telegram APIs yet.